# Maximum value of AND operation

Tags: c++, algorithm

Given two numbers A and B. Find the value of pair (P,Q) such that A <= P < Q <= B value of P AND Q is maximum where AND is a binary operator. Refer to this link for more information about AND operator

```
1<= A < B <=10^18
```

Code:

```
int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        long long int nearpow =0;
        int count=1;
        int a ; int b;
        cin>>a>>b;

        while(nearpow<=b){

            nearpow = 1<<count;
            count++;

        }
        nearpow/=2;

        if(nearpow==b){
            long long int x = b-1;
            long long int y = b-2;
            if(y>=a) cout<<(x&y)<<endl;
            else cout<<(b&x)<<endl;
        }else{
            long long int max=0;
            cout<<(b&(b-1))<<endl;

        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the wrong answer from this approach . where i am wrong ? Please Help

Comment: When you used the debugger, which line is causing issues?

Comment: This may be better posted to CodeReview@StackExchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When **b** is not a power of 2 you take answer to be **b&(b-1)** which is wrong. Suppose **b** is (**a** is very small suppose) **1001000**, **b-1** is **1000111** and their and is **1000000**.But the real answer is the and between **1000111** and **1000110** which is **1000110**.
So if its a power of 2 your solution is correct. 
If its not a power of 2 then answer should be **(b-1)&(b-2)** if  **b** is not odd otherwise **b&(b-1)**.
( apart from the corner case when only two numbers are there ie. if **a**=**b-1**)

Answer (score 0):

This code is in python but you can check the logic how this problem works

```
T=int(input())
    for i in range(T):
        A,B=list(map(int,input().split()))
        if(B%2==0):
            ans=B-2;
        else:
            ans=B-1;
        if(ans>=A):
            print(ans)
        else:
            print(A&B)
```